# Creating locationtech Geometry using org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON

Tags: geotools, jts-topology-suite

I am trying to create org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry from a json string using org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON.

```
import org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GeometryJSON geomJSON = new GeometryJSON();
        Geometry geometry = geomJSON.read("{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":{\"longitude\":65.0390625,\"latitude\":62.91523303947614,\"additionalElements\":[]}}");
        System.out.println(geometry);
        geometry = geomJSON.read("{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[{\"longitude\":80.5078125,\"latitude\":67.06743335108298,\"altitude\":1.0,\"additionalElements\":[]},{\"longitude\":81.2109375,\"latitude\":65.2198939361321,\"altitude\":1.0,\"additionalElements\":[]},{\"longitude\":74.1796875,\"latitude\":63.39152174400882,\"altitude\":1.0,\"additionalElements\":[]}]}");
        System.out.println(geometry);
    }
}
```

Point is read fine, but LineString is not read and gives error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LineString (found 1 - must be 0 or >= 2)
```

String is obtained by deserializing a json input as:

```
"geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            80.5078125,
            67.06743335108298,
            1
          ],
          [
            81.2109375,
            65.2198939361321,
            1
          ],
          [
            74.1796875,
            63.39152174400882,
            1
          ]
        ]
      }
```

How do get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You can only feed valid GeoJSON into the GeoTools geojson parsers - the strings you are using are not GeoJSON.

You need to read and understand the [GeoJSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946). From the [examples on page 22](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-22):

> Appendix A.  Geometry Examples
>
> Each of the examples below represents a valid and complete GeoJSON
> object.
>
> A.1.  Points
>
> Point coordinates are in x, y order (easting, northing for
> projected    coordinates, longitude, and latitude for geographic
> coordinates):
>
> ```
>  {
>      "type": "Point",
>      "coordinates": [100.0, 0.0]
>  }
> ```
>
> A.2.  LineStrings
>
> Coordinates of LineString are an array of positions (see    Section
> 3.1.1):
>
> ```
>  {
>      "type": "LineString",
>      "coordinates": [
>          [100.0, 0.0],
>          [101.0, 1.0]
>      ]
>  }
> ```